# Can I Record Limit on MyISAM Table?

Tags: mysql, myisam

I have a big data in myisam so a table's disk space is got full

so Can I Record Limit on MyISAM Table?

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "record limit"?

Do you mean "record the limit" or "limit the number of records"?

I'll assume the latter.

I believe the size of a MyISAM table is limited by the [maximum filesize](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/full-table.html) supported by the filesystem and the operating system. If your filesystem is limited to 2GB files, you can probably switch to a filesystem that supports larger files. You should probably consider changing the database back-end to InnoDB if your table sizes are approaching the limits.

The best approach may be to periodically check your database using `myisamchk`and take appropriate actions. I note it has this option

```
--data-file-length=len, -D len
Maximum length of the data file (when re-creating data file when it is “full”).
```

The [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/full-table.html) for full-tables says

> To change the default size limit for
>   MyISAM tables, set the
>   myisam_data_pointer_size, which sets
>   the number of bytes used for internal
>   row pointers. The value is used to set
>   the pointer size for new tables if you
>   do not specify the MAX_ROWS option.
>   The value of myisam_data_pointer_size
>   can be from 2 to 7. A value of 4
>   permits tables up to 4GB; a value of 6
>   permits tables up to 256TB.

and

> MySQL includes a MERGE library that
>   enables you to handle a collection of
>   MyISAM  tables that have identical
>   structure as a single MERGE table. See
>   Section 13.3,  “The MERGE Storage
>   Engine”.

Comment: Nail right on the head !!! +1 !!!